# How can we use Facebook,Twitter and other social authentication in Django Rest Framework

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

I am new to DRF token authentication and would like to implement Social Authentication such as facebook,twitter in my app. I have been reading [how-to-implement-oauth2-using-django-rest-framework](https://chrisbartos.com/articles/how-to-implement-oauth2-using-django-rest-framework/) but confused with a part:

What should i provide the **username** and **password** attributes if I'm using Facebook backend,Since those information is not passed by the user.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

Under the assumption that you're using DRF as an API to a front-end.

I'd suggest reading the following resources:

- [django-rest-auth](https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [hellojs](https://adodson.com/hello.js/#redirect-page)

Django rest auth is well documented and this should allow you to create auth tokens for your users. These should be used by your front-end and attached in the header of requests you make.

Hellojs is a great resource for adding auth to your front-end apps. Again well documented and fairly straightforward.

I've used it in conjunction with django-rest-auth in order to Log the user into your back-end API

Back end:

```
# Backend py
class TwitterLogin(SocialLoginView):
    serializer_class = TwitterLoginSerializer
    adapter_class = TwitterOAuthAdapter
```

Front end:

```
// front end js
const authRes = hello.getAuthResponse('twitter')
var auth_tokens = {
    "access_token": authRes.oauth_token ,
    "token_secret": authRes.oauth_token_secret
}
axios.post(REST_API_URL, auth_tokens)
.then((res) => {/** do something with token ex. store and use in further req.**/})
.catch((err) => console.log(err))
```

When you use twitter and facebook etc. you **never** ask for the users login credentials. This is considered to be poor practice. Instead you operated under oauth.

Which in short is like a multi stage verification of:

```
         User  ---  Twitter
           \         /    
           application
```

see: [oauth flow types](https://auth0.com/docs/api-auth/which-oauth-flow-to-use)

This is why I'd suggest using something like [hellojs](https://adodson.com/hello.js/#redirect-page) as it greatly simplifies the process of having to do all these verifications.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, m.k. was right. It is cool to use `hellojs`.

You need 2 django packages, actually: `django-allauth` and `django-rest-auth`.
You only need to POST your backend the 'access_token', the access-point is likely `/rest-auth/facebook/` which you'll need to set up by yourself as:

```
# urls.py:
from allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook.views import FacebookOAuth2Adapter
from rest_auth.registration.views import SocialLoginView

class FacebookLogin(SocialLoginView):
    adapter_class = FacebookOAuth2Adapter

urlpatterns = [
    ...
    url(r'^rest-auth/facebook/$', FacebookLogin.as_view(), name='fb_login'),
    ...
]

# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    ...
    'django.contrib.sites',  # for django-allauth

    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',  # token authentication
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    ...
]
SITE_ID = 1
SOCIALACCOUNT_PROVIDERS = {
    'facebook': {},
}
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend',
    'social_core.backends.facebook.FacebookOAuth2',
)
```

Then you need to set up your Facebook login app credentials in `/admin`.

Twitter must work pretty similar.

## Hello.js config

... will be something along these lines:

```
hello.init({
  facebook: fbId
})

export default {
  login (network) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
      hello(network).login({
        scope: 'email,public_profile'
      }).then(({ network, authResponse }) => {
        instance.post('/rest-auth/facebook/', {
          access_token: authResponse.access_token
        }).then(resolve, reject)
      })
    })
  }
}
```

You are in for token-based authentication, not session-cookie-based authentication.